# Translating sql to cypher queries

Tags: neo4j

Need help please to convert SQL queries to cypher queries.The owner of the organization wants to know how many orders are taken by each of the manager.

Query:

SELECT Manager_name,
Count(Order_id) AS number_of_orders
FROM Manager
INNER JOIN
sOrder ON Manager.Manager_id = sOrder.Manager_id
GROUP BY sOrder.Manager_id;

This is what I tried MATCH<-[:PRODUCT]-(:Order)<-[:PURCHASED]-(c:Customer)RETURN Manager_name.I am new to Neo4j so its been very tough for me

MATCH<-[:PRODUCT]-(:Order)<-[:PURCHASED]-(c:Customer)RETURN Manager_name

Comment: Your sql has Count on it, so what is equivalent in cypher?

Comment: Cn you please help

Comment: MATCH(:sOrder)<-[Sold]-(e:Manager)

Comment: RETURN Manager.name,Count(Order_id)As number _of_orders

Comment: @jose_bacoy is this one?still having errors.Thanks please